# boot-clj: install uberjar in maven repository

Tags: maven, jar, clojure, uberjar, boot-clj

Is is there a way to install an uberjar into a local maven repository?

Would it genereally a good place to store them or would it better to keep uberjar builds in a seperate directory? I mean, I was thinking og having a uberjar and a regular jar for each version in the local repository but I'm not sure with this.

Anyways, the following yields an error:

```
(boot (comp (pom) (uber) (jar) (install)))

-> .. "Multiple jar entries match': .*/pom.xml"
```

Comment: Have you looked into [bootlaces](https://github.com/adzerk-oss/bootlaces)? It's worked well for me [before](https://github.com/samestep/boot-refresh).